# Values in one Column different but second column the same SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an initial query written below and need to find values in the quote_id column that different but the corresponding values in the benefit_plan_cd column are the same. The output should look like the below. I know the prospect_nbr for this issue which is why I am able to add it to my initial query to get the expected results but need to be able to find other ones going forward.

```
select prospect_nbr, qb.quote_id, quote_type, effective_date, 
       benefit_plan_cd, package_item_cd
from   qo_benefit_data qb
       inner join
       qo_quote qq        on qb.quote_id = qq.quote_id
where  quote_type = 'R' 
  and  effective_date >= to_date('06/01/2022','mm/dd/yyyy')
  and  package_item_cd = 'MED'
```

Output should look like something like this excluding the other columns.

```
quote_id           benefit_plan_cd

514                      1234

513                      1234
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if you used table alias qualification on all columns in the `select` clause (not only on those that may be ambiguous since they exist in both tables). In any case: since `quote_id` exists in both tables, this means that both `quote_id` and `benefit_plan_cd` exist **in the same table** (either the first one or the second). And, if that is so, why do you need to get your answer (to the question you asked above) ***from the result of the query***? It doesn't look like the query has anything to do with your actual question. Are the other filters based on the other table?

Comment: so why do you have them at all in the select, it seems unecessary when you don't use aggreation functions

Comment: the other values in the select statement are just for additional information and the filters are to narrow down unwanted dates and other info. I am new to sql and am having trouble determining how to find values in one column that are different but the corresponding column have the same value as I illustrated above. Each quote_id is associated with a distinct number so in the example above 514 and 513 are tied to the same value. I need to know which prospect_nbr has two seperate quote_ids that have the same benefit_plan_cd.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do this in two steps.

First take your existing query and add the following at the end of your `select` list:

```
select ... /* the columns you have already */
       , count(distinct quote_id partition by benefit_plan_id) as ct
```

That is the **only** change - don't change anything else. You may want to run this first, to see what it produces. (Looking at a few rows should suffice, you don't need to look at all the rows.)

Then use this as a subquery, to filter on this count being > 1:

```
select ... /* only the ORIGINAL columns, without the one we added */
from   (
           /* write the query from above here, as a SUBquery */
       )
where  ct > 1
;
```